# How can I get toggle to collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working toggle function that expands and collapses but my list when expanded is very long and I wanted to put a "Close" link at the bottom to enable collapse so my users don't have to scroll to top to click and collapse. Any ideas how I can modify this code to expand it's functionality for my purposes?

```
<script language="javascript">
$(function(){
$(".formname").toggle(function(){
var id=$(this).attr('id');
$("#form"+id).fadeIn('slow');
},function(){
var id=$(this).attr('id');
$("#form"+id).fadeOut('slow');
}); 
});
</script>
```

my html looks like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="formxyz" class="formname">My Expanding/Collapsing Data</a></li>
<div style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li>Content</li>
</ul>
</div>
</ul>
```

if I insert the same link li at the bottom before the closing ul the user has to click it twice to collapse. I'd prefer a single click solution.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="formxyz" class="formname">My Expanding/Collapsing Data</a></li>
<div style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li>Content</li>
<li><a href="#" id="formxyz" class="formname">Close</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `toggle()` event on formxyz, the new close action will break the original rule, therefore sometimes you have to click formxyz twice to show content.

So use `click()` event with `fadeToggle()` action on formxyz. It will show content while it's hiding.

Then add a class on all "close", use `parents` method to find it's parents div (it should be the **content** div), then hide it.

The html:

```
 <div style="background-color: gray">
  <li><a href="#" id="xyz" class="formname">My Expanding/Collapsing Data</a></li>
  <div id="formxyz" class="content" style="display:none">
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li><a href="#" class="closeform">Close</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>​
</div>
```

The js file:

```
$(function(){
  $(".formname").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $("#form"+id).fadeToggle('slow').focus();
  }); 

  $(".closeform").click(function(){
    $(this).parents("div.content").fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

​

OR Check emulate code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qu8WP/). It's executable.

Comment: and also the `Close` link id shouldn't as same as `Expanding` title id.

Comment: This is more in line with what I'm hoping to achieve, though it closes all the divs on my page essentially leaving me with my bg color and nothing else. Is there a different element other than "parents" that can be used? Also, each time a link is clicked to expand, it takes the user to the top of the page.

Comment: so far, this does the trick
    $(this).closest("div").fadeOut('slow');

but still hoping to keep page from jumping to the top

Comment: Agh, yeah the `parent` can pass a selector in. Add a class on content div, then pass the new selector in parent. Check the jsFiddle, I've update it.

Comment: And about the expand problem, select an element and add a `focus()` action on it.

Comment: here's the solution:
    $(function() {
    $(".formname").toggle(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#form" + id).fadeIn('slow');

    }, function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#form" + id).fadeOut('slow');

    });


    $(".closeform").click(function() {
      $(this).closest("div").fadeOut('slow');
    });
    });

added some of yours to mine, then added an anchor tag to make the close link go to specific spot on page instead of top.

html close link

    <li><a href="#content" class="closeform">Close</a></li>

Comment: can you resend the jsfiddle, I didn't see your changes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><a href="#" id="xyz" class="formname">My Expanding/Collapsing Data</a></li>
<div style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li>Content</li>
<li><a href="#" id="xyz2" class="formname">Close</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

An id should be used for a single element. Never ever use the same id for more elements.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The ID is the same so it closes the correct div. If ID needs to be changed, then I would have to add an additional function to my js to tell it to close the specific div. Not sure on how to code that new function.

Comment: Nope, your function is based on the formname class. Both of your anchors inside your li tags have that class.

Comment: If you think I'm wrong, please show me where you use explicitly the xyz id in your javascript code.

Comment: Test your code when you rename the id of the second tag. Repeating ids in the HTML is one of the worst things a web developer can do.

Comment: I had edited my orig ? perhaps before you posted an answer to show that the id is really "formxyz". I totally agree that IDs should not be repeated. Changing the id on the close link however, doesn't solve this issue alone.

Comment: You didn't follow my suggestion. You still have two occurrences of the same id, but now the repeated id is formxyz. Your change obviously didn't solve this issue, because you are still using an id twice.

Comment: Please, just test once exactly my suggestion and you will see it's correct and you will also understand the cause of the issue. Obviously you didn't test my suggestion, please help me to help you.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use the id "xyz" twice or you use the id "formxyz" twice. It is the same bug.